# Getting "This browser does not support speech recognition" error

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am enabling speech recognizer option in my bot.
In localhost I am not getting below error after adding `speechrecognizer` code.
But after publishing it in Azure, I am getting this error:

```
"This browser does not support speech recognition."
```

Getting above error in page load itself. I have tried different browsers but get the same error.

The same code with a different subscription Key is working fine in another Azure environment.

What could the reason be for this error?

```
speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({
        subscriptionKey:
        '*****'
    }),
    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
        gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
        subscriptionKey: '*****',
        voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
    })
};
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Can you add more of your Web Chat code? Are you using Web Chat v3 or v4?

Comment: I am using chrome. Same code working in Localhost. if i run above mentioned code in console in azure site I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.
This is not an issue with code:-)
Site has to be secured.
Changing http to https resolved this issue.